# Realm-Android How to search a list of objects who contains certains object

Tags: java, android, realm

I would like have a query regarding an object, which in turn has an attribute, which is another object, but not if it can be done directly.
I use this function:

```
public static RealmList<Action_DB> getActions(Realm realm, int id){

    Holograma_DB holo = realm.where(Holograma_DB.class).equalTo("id",id).findFirst();

    return realm.where(Action_DB.class).equalTo("holo",holo).findAll();

}
```

The class Action_DB is:

```
public class Action_DB extends RealmObject{

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private String a;

private Video_DB v;

private int ver;

private Holograma_DB holo;
...
}
```

In return I get a syntax fault and I do not know if it's because I'm not doing well or can not do.

Now I have a possible solution if they could not make the list of actions associated with Hologram object, but I wonder if it is possible to do everything in the query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot query equalTo with objects, only String, int, long, etc. See [RealmQuery](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html) for a complete list.

In your case you might query on the `id` of the `holo` variable

```
Holograma_DB holo = realm.where(Holograma_DB.class).equalTo("id",id).findFirst();
return realm.where(Action_DB.class).equalTo("holo.id", holo.getId()).findAll();
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: @TimCastelijins At the moment I can't try the solution, but when I can try this solution I check your answer.
Anyway it is a good solution if it could be carried out, and solves my doubts combine objects